# mobile stylesheet not working on iPhones

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

I've just written some rules in order to display the mobile version of my website on smartphones.

Mobile rules are included at the bottom of the default stylesheet ( http://www.flapane.com/style.css ) using "@media".

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px), only screen and (orientation : landscape) and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)
 { [CODE]
}
```

I succesfully tested it on a 480x800 Android device. It works both in landscape and portrait mode. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/grnJr.png )

However I tested it on a couple of friends'iPhone4, and desktop version is always  displayed.

I tried using just

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
```

but nothing changed.

Any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px), only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 800px) and (orientation : landscape), only screen and (device-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
```

seems to work on iPhone too

Answer (score 0):

Change `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)` to:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)
```

as in [this example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), and it should be working. That page is also a good bookmark for future reference.

Comment: Thanks, that was the first page I read before attempting to create a mobile stylesheet. I tried with using your code, but nothing changed (I changed my Firefox user agent). That's weird, considering that Google and Stackoverflow switched to mobile layout after I changed my user agent. Honestly, I don't have any clue.

Comment: Hmm, very strange. I just ran your code through the CSS validator and it spat out "landscape is not a orientation value". Try removing parts of the media query, esp. the orientation part, and see if anything works...

Comment: Yep I noted that error (even if landscape is a known value for orientation). However I tested your code by deleteing everything in the media query and then using your snippet only, in order to avoid conflicts. When I noticed that nothing changed, I reverted to the original version containing the orientation part and the rest.

Comment: I think I've got it! Remove the words 'only' and 'device' from the widths, so your arguments look like this: `@media screen and (min-width : 320px)`

Comment: Thanks, done! Do you have an iPhone4? I don't, and most of the emulators on the web require Safari.

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. I tried with an iPhone emulator in Chrome (also WebKit) but your CSS at [flapane.com](http://flapane.com) does not seem to have changed? Should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: That's the correct address. I really don't know what's wrong. If you browse it with an Andorid device, the mobile version is shown, so the @media section seems to be correctly read by the browser parser.

Comment: It finally seems to work, I asked a friend and he sent me a couple of screenshoot. I wonder what was wrong, I just rewrote the `only` and `device` parts you suggested me to remove and somehow it worked. Here are a couple of screens in landscape and portrait mode he sent me: http://imageshack.us/g/685/img1260j.png/